# option in form field hides option in next field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I am trying to get the "10.30am" option to dissapear in the Workshop Time field when "Monday 13th April" is selected in the Workshop date field. Failing that I would be happy if the option just disabled.

```
<div class="form-group">
<form action="ksmail.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <p class="control-label blue">Workshop Date:</p>
            <select name="date" class="finput" id="wdate">
                <option value="11th_APR">Saturday 11th April</option>
                <option value="13th_APR" id="dt">Monday 13th     April</option>
                <option value="18th_APR">Saturday 18th April</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <p class="control-label blue">Workshop Time:</p>
            <select name="time" class="finput" id="wtime">
                <option value="9am" id="tn">9am</option>
                <option value="10_30am" id="tt">10.30am</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$('#wtime') .show();  
$('#wdate').bind('change', function (e) {   
if( $('#wdate').val() == "#dt") {  
    $('#tt').hide();  
}
```

css

```
#wtime{display: none;}
```

I have tried many variations of this none of which work. Sorry, I am a jquery newbie/moron. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition seem wrong. Try this one, hope this helped :

```
$('#wtime').show();  
 $('#wdate').on('change', function (e) { 

  if( $(this).val() == "13th_APR") {  
    $('#tt').hide();  
  }
  else
  {
    $('#tt').show();
  }
});
```

Comment: this should work. You would need to add an else to the if as well to show() the option otherwise.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer but it didn't work for me. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/t0xrtxyv/6/

Comment: @RE01. your jsfiddle page is missing jquery plugin. Add it from the left side. here is the updated code http://jsfiddle.net/t0xrtxyv/8/

Comment: @RE01, jsfiddle is missing jquery like Bala said.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to disable the option

```
 $('#wdate').on('change', function (e) { 
  if( $(this).val() == "13th_APR") {  
  $("#wtime option[value='10_30am']").attr('disabled','disabled');
  }
});
```

or if you want to remove the option

```
 $('#wdate').on('change', function (e) { 
  if( $(this).val() == "13th_APR") {  
   $("#wdate option[value='10_30am']").remove();
  }
});
```

Hope this helps